# Как создать простой товар через API woocommerce (python)?

Tags: python, wordpress, woocommerce

Первый раз работаю с API, поэтому нужна помощь. Многого не требуется, необходимо лишь создать товар со своими: названием, ценой и картинкой. Документация прочел, но не до конца понял, было бы хорошо увидеть пример готового кода для создания товара.
По документации заполнил авторизацию, добавил ссылку на сайт, а также ключи. Также по документации сделал товар на добавление, но выдает ошибку. В этом разобраться и не могу:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/API/test.py", line 23, in <module>
print(wcapi.post("products", data).json())
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
packages\requests\models.py", line 898, in json
return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\USer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38- 
32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38- 
32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38- 
32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Документация содержит подробные примеры. Начните с [авторизации](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#rest-api-keys).

Установите модуль для `python`

```
pip install woocommerce
```

Следующий код производит авторизацию и создает товар. Данный пример подробно описан в [документации](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-a-product). Даже с примером кода на `python`.

```
from woocommerce import API

wcapi = API(
    url="http://example.com",
    consumer_key="ck_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    consumer_secret="cs_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    version="wc/v3"
)

data = {
    "name": "Товар 1",
    "type": "simple",
    "regular_price": "777",
    "description": "Мое описание",
    "short_description": "Короткое описание",
    "images": [
        {
            "src": "http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_front.jpg"
        }
    ]
}

print(wcapi.post("products", data).json())
```

Comment: Добавил ошибку которая возникает при выполнении кода

Comment: @Just_Bruh вы добавили свои данные в параметры `API`? Ваша ошибка говорит о том, что полученный ответ не содержит данных для перевода в `json`.

Comment: Да, ключи сгенерировал на woocommerce, в параметры добавил ссылку и ключи

Comment: @Just_Bruh смените `.json()` на `text`

Comment: Результат:

    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
    <html><head>
    <title>404 Not Found</title>
    </head><body>
    <h1>Not Found</h1>
    <p>The requested URL /wp-json/wc/v3/products was not found on this server.</p>
    <hr>
    <address>Apache/2.4.6 Server at f0443823.xsph.ru Port 80</address>
    </body></html>

Comment: @Just_Bruh на сайте к которому вы обращаетесь нет пути для запроса к `/wp-json/wc/v3/products`. С этим мне нечем помочь. Я не знаю как работает эта система.

Comment: Спасибо, более менее разобрался, единственное зачем сменили .json() на .text?

Comment: @Just_Bruh запрос выполняется неверно, с ошибкой. Поэтому в ответ возвращается не ожидаемый `json`, а сама ошибка. Чтобы ее посмотреть сменили на `text`. Также странно, что ответ пришел в виде `html`. Похоже, что сам сайт не умеет отвечать на запросы.

Answer (score 0):

Не правильно созданы данные по товару, пропущен "product"

data = {
"product": {
"title": "Premium Quality",
"type": "simple",
"regular_price": "21.99",
"description": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.",
"short_description": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.",
"categories": [
9,
14
],
"images": [
{
"src": "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/premium-quality-front.jpg",
"position": 0
},
{
"src": "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/premium-quality-back.jpg",
"position": 1
}
]
}
}

Comment: а какое отношение вами написанное имеет к вопросу?

Comment: в коде выше допущена ошибка